# How can i insert data to nested document (date) with input field?

Tags: mongodb

I want insert data to my nested field `date` with input field.

For the field `name` i can easily insert new data input, but when i want to insert new data to the field `date` (inside `name`) he cannot get the input value/not insert to field `date`.

Sorry for my bad English :(

[image: PHOTO]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using **updateOne()** and **$set** you can conquer

```
var query  = {"name.date":"value_of_data"} 
const res = await Customer_Name.updateOne({_id:"value_of_id"},{$set:query})
```